# Piwik - Track user progress for an elearning system

Tags: analytics, matomo, reward-system

We are in the process of designing a simple e-learning site, where our registered users and site administrators can see valuable statistical info about the user progress.

we want to track what topics they have visited the most, content "liked", other user profiles visited, and maybe even add a reward system on top of that (points, badges, unlocking content) for finishing courses, watching videos, participating in discussion, or helping people.

Now I have been looking into Piwik as a potential analytics package for our website, and I know it is possible to track individual users by adding a unique "visitor_id" to the API calls. Is it possible for me to track and **retrieve** the information I described above using Piwik out of the box? Should I create my own plug in? Should I be looking at something different?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

You can build most of this using Piwik Custom Variables and Segmentation features. But, it might require a custom plugin for some of your requirements.